# Problem with passing data from one structore to another using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dma

I have a problem with addressing of data

I'm trying to pass all the data from one structure to another in one go using pointers

When I do this way:

```
#define ADDRESS_SPACE 8

struct dma_engine
{
    int (*Address)[ADDRESS_SPACE] = {nullptr};
};

struct data_engine
{
    int data[ADDRESS_SPACE] = {0x10,0x14,0x18,0x1B,0x20,0x24,0x28,0x2B};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    dma_engine  Dma_0;
    data_engine Data_0;

    Dma_0.Address = &Data_0.data; 
    
    for(int i = 0;i <ADDRESS_SPACE;i++)
    {
        printf("*Dma_0.Address[%d] ---> 0x%x\n",i,*Dma_0.Address[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I receive only first correct element of the data[ADDRESS_SPACE] array:

```
*Dma_0.Address[0] ---> 0x10
*Dma_0.Address[1] ---> 0x96408360
*Dma_0.Address[2] ---> 0x77a39b80
*Dma_0.Address[3] ---> 0xb6072bc0
*Dma_0.Address[4] ---> 0x0
*Dma_0.Address[5] ---> 0x0
*Dma_0.Address[6] ---> 0x96408368
*Dma_0.Address[7] ---> 0x0
```

Is there a way to pass all the correct data in one go rather than handle every element of an array individually?

Many Thanks

Comment: I think your problem lies in the fact `dma_engine.Address` is an _array of `int*`_. Not  the same as an _array of int_ like `data_engine.data`. So, you only copy a pointer and don't read/write it correctly. Not that I understand what you want to do.

Comment: Your usage of indirection and deref isn't doing what you think, and specifically operator precedence of `*` against `[]` is borking your attempt.  `*Dma_0.Address[i]` should be `(*Dma_0.Address)[i]` . Run your program through an address sanitizer and you'll see you're loop is breaching memory it shouldn't with your current (incorrect) dereference strategy.

Comment: @NoDataFound and the OP isn't declaring `Address` as an array of `int*`; that would be `int *Address[ADDRESS_SPACE]` . The code declares a pointer  to array-of-8-int, strongly typed. This prevents anything *other* than the address of a native array-of-8-int from being set there.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, the (*Dma_0.Address)[i] did everything. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you truly desire a strongly-typed pointer-to-array as your `Address` member, the code you have is not dereferencing the target array correctly during your print loop. Specifically, this:

```
*Dma_0.Address[i]
```

That member is a pointer to array-of-8-int. The syntax applies *both* `*` and `[i]` in the same expression against the same operand, which is not what you want. `[]` has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*` in C when applied in this context.

Therefore you may think that expression means:

- dereference the pointer-to-array using `*` to get the base array
- apply `[i]` against that array to acquire the desired `i`'th element.

But in actuality what you're asking is:

- find the `i`'th array-of-8-int, starting at the specified address.
- use `*` to acquire the first element of that array

**Solution**

Assuming you want to retain all of your existing type usage, the solution is to simply force the evaluation of `*` *first* by encasing it in something with higher priority than `[]` . Expression parenthesis has the highest priority in the language, and will deliver what you desire.

Therefore,

```
(*Dma_0.Address)[i]
```

which says: evaluate `*Dma_0.Address` before applying `[i]` to the result. This one change in your program produces the following output*:

```
*Dma_0.Address[0] ---> 0x10
*Dma_0.Address[1] ---> 0x14
*Dma_0.Address[2] ---> 0x18
*Dma_0.Address[3] ---> 0x1b
*Dma_0.Address[4] ---> 0x20
*Dma_0.Address[5] ---> 0x24
*Dma_0.Address[6] ---> 0x28
*Dma_0.Address[7] ---> 0x2b
```

which I suspect is what you're really after.

<sub>* I did not bother changing any of the printf messaging, opting only to change the problematic argument, when I tested this, in case that wasn't obvious</sub>